# ChartJS Data Overflowing Chart area

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas, chart.js

I have a chart created with ChartJS that displays datasets ( (x,y) pairs) in a line chart. Based on user requests, I am adding the ability for the user to change the X-max and Y-max values. All well and good until the datasets overflow the Chart area.

[image: Wiggly data]

This is off the right side of the chart, in the blank space under the legend. As you can see, the lines stop following the points and go crazy until they are clipped by the canvas area.

I would like to clip or mask the visible data using the Chart area, rather than the Canvas area. Is there a setting in ChartJS to do this?

Edit: clarified title

Answer (score 0):

I've found a partial solution. By adding `lineTension: 0` to the `Chart.dataset` object, I was able to get the following:

[image: No more wiggles]

Changing the line tension to 0 has eliminated the wavy lines outside of the chart area, but I'm still looking for a solution to the data overflow.